# insert a shell script declared variable into HTML heading

Tags: html, shell

I have a variable that am declaring like below in my shell script:

`Variable = awk 'Some code' filename.txt` << this is assigning one word from the text file to this variable

And then am trying to display this in an HTML heading like below, but its not working.

```
<h2><font color="navy"> Network-element : ${variable} </font></h2>
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there could be 2 points here.

1- Cover the variable value like:

```
Variable=$(awk 'Some code' filename.txt)
```

2- Then in shell script html code doesn't work like simple print you have to use echo for it (NOTE this is only an example)eg->

```
echo "<html>" > $OUTPUT_FILE
echo "<title>" >> $OUTPUT_FILE
echo "A Test script." >> $OUTPUT_FILE
echo "</title>" >> $OUTPUT_FILE
echo "</body>" >> $OUTPUT_FILE
echo "</html>" >> $OUTPUT_FILE
```

This above code is only an example where I am putting echo statements into output file. You could use it as per your use case. Also use `"$Variable"` in `echo` command.

Comment: Thanks for it, that's what was needed and it worked perfectly:)